# UAA Federation: How to return group information back to relying party?

Tags: cloudfoundry-uaa

After configuring two UAA instances as federated, say UAA1 (Relying party)--uses--> UAA2(ID provider) through OIDC mechanism, I can use UAA1 to authenticate users defined on UAA2 through authentication code work flow. UAA1 defines shadow users in its instance, but it does not capture groups defined for users on UAA2.

For example, user1_uaa2 is on UAA2 and it belongs to a groups called uaa.test. After login through UAA1, a shadow user user1_uaa2 is created in UAA1, but its group information is lost.

How can a user's group information be propagated back to relying party in OIDC based UAA federation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think according to source code, that in last version of UAA (V4.10), UAA only returns openid as scope in id_token and /userinfo, no matter if the access token has roles scope or not. That means as either OIDC or SAML identity provider, it does not provide user group information.

It seems to me its codes work and are able to retrieve group information when UAA works as SP or proxy to other IDPs. It store those information to user_info table.